# How to show table like information in Nagios?

Tags: snmp, nagios

My setup is something like this.
I have multiple servers. Each server has multiple instances of same service (multi-tenant like architecture). Now I want to get status of all services running on all servers using SNMP.
The problem I am facing is, how can someone show table like information in Nagios?

i.e. when I click on any particular server, it will show me list of services. Now when I click on any service, it should again give me the list of instances of that particular service.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such a feature in Nagios. You will need to set up a check for each of the services running on the monitored host.